# How to Inject IHostedService in Dependecy injection from Autofac Module

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I am trying to use Autofac Di container to build dependencies instead of .netcore default `IServiceCollection`. I Need to inject `IHostedService`. `IServiceCollection` has method `AddHostedService` but I can not find alternative method in Autofac `ContainerBuilder`.

Autofac Documentation says that you can populate `ContainerBuilder` from `IServiceCollection` so one solution would be to add IHostedService in IServiceCollection and then populate ContainerBuilder from it but I have multiple AutofacModule, some of them registering each other and they each have responsibility for their services and to inject some service from ChildModule directly in Startup does not seem right.

```
 public class ParentModule : Module
 {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.RegisterModule(new ChildModule());
    }
 }

 public class ChildModule : Module
 {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       //TODO Add hosted service here.
    }
 }

 public class Startup
 {
   ...
   ...
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      var container = new ContainerBuilder();
      container.RegisterModule(new ParentModule());

      return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
   }
   ...
   ...
 }
```

Eventually I want to pack ParentModule in package and upload it in custom NugetServer so i can just add ParentModule wherever i need it without remembering to inject some services in IServiceCollection.

My modules are much complex and on multiple level depth so simple extension method for IServiceCollection to add additional dependencies is not an option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just register them like this

```
builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>()
       .As<IHostedService>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

The host (web-host or regular host) takes care of resolving all those registrations of `IHostedService` and runs them.

The extension method `AddHostedService<THostedService>` doesn't do anything different as you can see

```
public static IServiceCollection AddHostedService<THostedService>(this IServiceCollection services)
where THostedService : class, IHostedService
{
   return services.AddTransient<IHostedService, THostedService>();
}
```

You can find the source-code on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/ServiceCollectionHostedServiceExtensions.cs#L19).

### UPDATE 2022-03-15

As pointed out in the comments, the MS registration is using singletons now. While it technically doesn't matter for this specific case, if you want to align it with the MS registration, you would need to do the following

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>()
       .As<IHostedService>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if i register multiple IHostedServices all ```.As<IHostedService>``` autofac will create IEnumerable<IHostedService> and "webhost-builder" will resolve and run all of them right ?

Comment: Yes, it will return an enumeration of IHostedService and then all of them will be started by the web-host.

Comment: If I would have read this answer at the beginning of my problem, I would have saved 1-2h of looking for a solution since I have been doing both autofac and HostedService registration, but I had problem with named parameters.

Comment: I think builder.Register<MyHostedService>() should be builder.RegisterType<MyHostedService>(), no ?

Comment: Good catch! Thanks, I've updated the post.

Comment: Just worth mentioning that it's not a transient dependency anymore but a singleton. You can check the github link from the answer and it has changed.